# how to cut down the NASM program into parts...?

Tags: nasm

I am currently learning NASM and there are many things that go unexplained in the textbooks. I've gotten to used to the "well that's the way it is so accept it" answers from professors and in answers to some of my other questions, but I've also gotten better at knowing which answers have a better chance of getting a real answer

What is the technical reason NASM programs are broken down into three sections--`.data`, `.bss` and `.text`? What is really happening behind the scenes? Why does the assembler need to know in advance if there are constants, why not just take them as the program goes?

Answer (score 0):

the `data` section is where all of your initialized data goes.  Strings, DWORDS, WORDS, BYTES, QWORDS, etc, anything that needs to have a value when the program starts.  This section is read/write.  Also, anything here **does** add to the final exe size, so if you have a really long string; say 200 bytes, your program will be 200 bytes bigger than if you didn't have this string.

the `bss` section is where all of your uninitialized data goes anything that does not need a value when the program starts.  Anything added here **does not** add to the final exe size.  What you put here, tells the exe loader to allocate memory for such and such variables as they will need room in memory during the program execution.  This section is read/write.

the `text` section is where all program code goes.  This section is read-only.

You can change the attributes to each section if wanted, and you can create your own sections if needed.

All of this can be found through research.